# How to check what I fetched?

Tags: git

I work in a project that has many branches. For example I have only console for git now. I do:

```
git fetch --all
```

How can I check which branches are fetched?

In programs with GUI this is showed, so how can I do it in console?

Comment: use "git branch" to se all branches.

Comment: git branch doesn't work in this situation

Comment: @kirtilukke I find argoo's advice very welcome, I didn't mention it in my answer but yes, it can be useful to see a list of your branches. However, to see where they're pointing to, and also their remote counterparts, I'd suggest to use the (very) verbose version, `git branch -vv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you can do

```
git fetch --all --dry-run
```

to output what *would* be fetched, without *actually* fetching anything ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---dry-run)).

Very handy when you want to be sure of what you're doing, since `fetch` is by default set as a forced update, so rewritten histories could be something you'd want to intercept (in some cases) before you update your remote-tracking branches.

---

Then inspecting your branches can be done in many ways, but let's mention

- a simple `git branch`, with in mind the possibility of adding a `-v` flag to more thoroughly inspect where each branch points to and which remote counterpart is its associated source for push/pull.
- `git log`, like choroba already [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56637380/1057485).

However let's add that graphs in console output are sometimes difficult to read, namely with many branches. Consider the `--simplify-by-decoration` flag in that case.

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --all
```

Or even more sophisticated tools like `gitk` and many more.

---

**Sidenote:** How to read `fetch` output (in answer to Borea's comment below)

```
remote:
remote:   Here can be (optional) messages from your remote
remote:   (depending on your remote settings)
remote:
From https://somewhere.com/path/to/your/remote/repo
 * [new branch]            XYZ-555-broken-feature-foo -> origin/XYZ-555-broken-feature-foo
   142e976..de5a418        master                 -> origin/master
   9b7abb4..1eb8c0f        develop                -> origin/develop
 + 63d7613a51...f50aa46186 XYZ-552-feature-bar    -> origin/XYZ-552-feature-bar  (forced update)
 * [new tag]               v4.2.0                 -> v4.2.0
 - [deleted]               hotfix/XYZ-550
```

In the output example above, we can read that:

- a new `XYZ-555-broken-feature-foo` branch has been created on the remote, and now your local repo knows of it. Note that you still don't have a *local* `XYZ-555-broken-feature-foo` branch. But your repo stored the commit this remote branch points to under a remote-tracking ref named `origin/XYZ-555-broken-feature-foo`. It will be updated upon each fetch command to reflect its remote state. (By fetch command I mean `fetch` or `pull` which both fetch remote refs)
- `master` and `develop` branches have been updated on the remote. For example, `master` was pointing at commit `142e976` last time you fetched, but is now pointing at commit `de5a418`. This also means that your local counterparts of these branches now are `N commits behind` and would need a `pull` to be up-to-date again.
- the `XYZ-552-feature-bar` branch has been force-pushed by someone and it breaks history with *your* local `XYZ-552-feature-bar` branch. You'll probably need to `reset --hard @{u}` from this branch to adopt this new history and avoid conflicts (or alternatively, push your local version with `--force` to bring back the changes someone pushed "out"). Be sure to discuss this with the involved coworkers.
- There is a new tag `v4.2.0`
- The `hotfix/XYZ-550` branch has been deleted on the remote (*You* might still have a local version, though, which remains untouched by `fetch`).

*(I've added this last example of a deleted branch, but you'd have to use `-p` in your `fetch` command to possibly have these. See [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt--p) for the `--prune` option)*

Comment: Whether I use `git branch` or `git log` to see what I've just fetched, what am I looking for in the output that tells me what I've just fetched?

Answer (score 1):

Use git log with the following parameters:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

Comment: I kinda feel like your `-vv` version here, @choroba :-)